# Run-time error '1004': Unable to get VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, combobox, runtime-error, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to make an application on vba in excel. I want the labels to be filled according to the registry number selected in ComboRegister. However, while I am not getting any error for the first 5 lines, I am getting 'Unable to get VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class' error in the other lines(in exel). I even get a 'type mismatch' error on line 8(in exel)i(x = ComboRegister.Text in vba). What is the reason for getting such an error even though I don't do anything different from the other lines? I would be glad if you help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Private Sub ComboRegister_Change()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String
Dim G_GUN As Double
Dim D_GUN As Double
Dim G_KON As Double
Dim D_KON As Double

If ComboRegister.Text <> "" Then
x = ComboRegister.Text
'Range("c1").Value = ComboRegister.Text


 LabelPerAd.Caption = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheets("LOOKUP").Range("B2:K10"), 3, False)
  LabelIdf.Caption = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheets("LOOKUP").Range("B2:K10"), 2, False)
   LabelDeg.Caption = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheets("LOOKUP").Range("B2:K10"), 4, False)
```

Comment: The value returned by `ComboRegister.Text` is a text value.  So when it's assigned to `x`, the text value is converted into an Integer, since `x` is declared as an Integer.  However, if it can't be converted into an Integer, you'll get a type mismatch error.

Comment: If the values in your lookup range are formatted and recognized as text values, instead of numerical values, then you'll get an `Unable to get VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class` error, since `x` is an Integer.  In this case, you would need to declared `x` as a String.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. but when I make changes as you said, this time I get an error from other lines. Also, when I select registry on lines 9 and 10, I get no output. When I select only these lines, I get 'Run-time error '1004': Unable to get VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class'. (Also, the regisrt in the 8th line in the first picture should be DGY864. There was some mistake)